# Iterating over two iterables

Tags: python, serialization

I've written a little function that iterates over two iterables. The first one returns an object which is used to convert an object of the second iterable. I've got a working implementation, but would like to get some feedback.

A simple use case would look like this:

```
list(serialize([String(), String()], [1, 2]))    # should work
list(serialize([String(), String()], range(3)))  # should fail, too many values
list(serialize([String(), String()], range(1)))  # should fail, too few values
```

But sometimes the number of values is not known but the type is the same. Therefore infinite iterators should be allowed as types argument:

```
list(serialize(it.repeat(String()), range(3)))   # should work
```

Of course finite iterators are allowed as well:

```
list(serialize(it.repeat(String(), times=3), range(3))) # should work
list(serialize(it.repeat(String(), times=4), range(5))) # should fail
# should fail, but probably not that easy to do.
list(serialize(it.repeat(String(), times=4), range(3)))
```

My working implementation (except for the last case) looks like this:

```
class String(object):
    def dump(self, value):
        return str(value)

def serialize(types, values):
    class Stop(object):
        """Since None can be valid value we use it as fillvalue."""

    if isinstance(types, collections.Sized):
        # Since None is a valid value, use a different fillvalue.
        tv_pairs = it.izip_longest(types, values, fillvalue=Stop)
    else:
        tv_pairs = it.izip(it.chain(types, (Stop,)), values)

    for type, value in tv_pairs:
        if type is Stop:
            raise ValueError('Too many values.')
        if value is Stop:
            raise ValueError('Too few values.')
        yield type.dump(value)
```

Comment: you could be checking to see if the lengths of the two lists match instead of messing around with `izip`?

Comment: @omouse This won't work if a generator is used.

Answer (score 1):

There is no (general) way of telling the difference between an infinite and a finite iterator.

`types` might be a generator that stops yielding after a million items have been yielded.  The only fool-proof way of telling would be to consume the generator up to the point where it stops yielding items.  Of course, even if we've consumed a billion items and it hasn't stopped, we can't be sure it wouldn't stop at a later point.

This is why I recommend you change the specification for your function.  The new version will yield items until `values` have been up.  If there are too few `types`, it raises `ValueError`.

```
def serialize(types, values):
    types_iter = iter(types)
    for value in values:
        try:
            type = next(types_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            raise ValueError("Too few types.")
        yield type.dump(value)
```

If you really want to, you can check with `len()` that the lengths of `types` and `values` are the same, but as you have said, this will only work for some iterables.

```
def serialize(types, values):
    try:
        len_types, len_values = len(types), len(values)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        if len_values > len_types:
            raise ValueError("Too many values.")
        if len_values < len_types:
            raise ValueError('Too few values.')

        for type, value in itertools.izip(types, values):
            yield type.dump(value)
        return

    types_iter = iter(types)
    for value in values:
        try:
            type = next(types_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            raise ValueError("Too many values.")
        yield type.dump(value)
```